# Socket.IO and load balancer (ALB AWS)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, websocket, socket.io, aws-application-load-balancer

I've a server that handle HTTP request and Socket.IO service.

My app is running on multiple threads and my socket.io instance are linked to each other thanks to Redis.

Everything is working in local and on production environnement without LB.

Once I setup 2 instances through an Application Load Balancer connections to my server are failing due to transport error ( {"type":"TransportError","description":400})

But if I try to connect by ip address directly (To one server) it's working.

The issue seems te be the load balancer, I tried a million things and I don't have any idea anymore...

I activated Stickiness and my target groups, no changes.

It's like my server accepting Websockets only but not polling.

In my client, if I just set websocket as protocol it's working, but if I set polling and websocket, it's not working.

Hope someone can helpe me with this issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [here](https://socket.io/how-to/deal-with-cookies#nodejs-client-and-cookies), Socket.IO Client don't handle cookies out of the box and ALB use cookies to redirect to the right server.

To fix this issue I need to put that code in client side

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import { parse } from "cookie";

const socket = io("https://my-domain.com");
const COOKIE_NAME = "AWSALB";

socket.io.on("open", () => {
  socket.io.engine.transport.on("pollComplete", () => {
    const request = socket.io.engine.transport.pollXhr.xhr;
    const cookieHeader = request.getResponseHeader("set-cookie");
    if (!cookieHeader) {
      return;
    }
    cookieHeader.forEach(cookieString => {
      if (cookieString.includes(`${COOKIE_NAME}=`)) {
        const cookie = parse(cookieString);
        socket.io.opts.extraHeaders = {
          cookie: `${COOKIE_NAME}=${cookie[COOKIE_NAME]}`
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```